# PHP switch statement POST or GET

Tags: php, switch-statement

I'm starting to learn PHP and I want to make a switch statement with a `<select>` option. The idea is that you select a brand like Volvo, and when you've selected Volvo the types will come up in a second  box. After this you will be able to select a color and materials but let's start with the first select box.

HTML:

```
<p>Brand: <form action="?" method="post"><select name="brand">
<option value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
<option value="BMW">BWM</option>
<option value="porche">Porche</option></select>
<input type="submit value="submit"">
</form></p>
<p>Type: <?php echo $type; ?></p>
```

PHP:

```
switch($brand) {
    case 'Volvo':
        $type = '<?php echo $typeVolvo; ?>';
    break;
    case 'BMW':
        $type = '<?php echo $typeBMW; ?>';
    break;
    case 'porche':
        $type = '<?php echo $typePorche; ?>';
    break;
    default: 
        $type = 'Select a brand';
}
```

I've also tried `switch($_GET['serie'])` or with POST but I can't seem to find the right solution for this one. `$typePorche` is also included underneath this code.

Comment: There is a lot wrong with your code, so it is hard to give you an answer

Comment: oh my god ... start learning html basic html only the select has a name-tag .. the options have value="proche" and not name="porsche" ... then understand server <-> client communication (request) after you fetch it under php $_POST['brand'] you can do your switch

Comment: My HTML is good. I've made a small mistake by doing name instead of value. The actual code has value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<option>` tags needs `value` attribute, not `name`. And on the PHP side, you need to use `$_POST['brand']`

Comment: Sorry, you're correct. In my actual code i've value instead of name. And when I trie $_POST['brand'] it gives me a "Undefined index: serie".

Comment: How can a `$_POST['brand']` give `Undefined index: serie`, when index is a hardcoded `brand`? You probably have totally different code than showed here.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can directly code like bwlow to avoid switch case

```
            <p>Brand: <form action="?" method="post"><select name="brand">
            <option value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
            <option value="BMW">BWM</option>
            <option value="porche">Porche</option></select>
            <input type="submit value="submit"">
            </form></p>

            <?php
                if(isset($_POST['brand'])) {
                    $type = $_POST['brand'];
                }
            ?>
```